# Android WebView Set Custom UA With Android OS Version

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to set Custom User Agent for my Android WebView App with App Version & Android OS.

I am using the following function for doing so:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; FixMatka v1.0 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```

I want to set the users' device's **Android Version** in place of `Android 5.1.1`

Also, if possible users' device's **Chrome Version** in place of `Chrome/43.0.2357.65`

& users' device's **Build Version** in place of `Build/LMY48B;`

How do I do it? Please explain step by step. I am relatively new in Android Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String OSVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(String.format("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android %s; FixMatka v1.0 Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Mobile Safari/537.36", OSVersion));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the activity of the webview, create a new string, in MainActivity.java i.e..

```
String MyUA = "UA";
```

Now Set the String

```
mywebView.getSettings() .setUserAgentString(MyUA);
```

This Way:

[image]